# Can a particle be identified when one knows $\left<dE/dx\right>$ and the Cherenkov angle $\theta_c$?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, data-analysis, elementary-particles, cherenkov-radiation

I have a question about if it would be possible to identify a particle by measuring the energy loss due to ionization $\langle dE/dx\rangle$ and the Cherenkov angle $\theta_c$. I assume that we know what the material properties ($n$, $\rho$, $Z$ and $A$) are although that's not given explicitly.

#### My attempt at an answer:

I have two equations, one for the Cherenkov angle ($\beta = 1/n \cos \theta_c$) from which I can retrieve the ratio $p_X/m_X$, and one for the energy loss (the Bethe formula as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula)) which I can solve for $\frac{z^2}{m_X}$. But as far as I know I have 3 unknowns: the momentum of the particle $p_X$, the mass of the particle $m_X$, and the charge of the particle $z_X$.

So I guess that I can obtain at best a ratio $m_X/z^2$ with those two measurements, which is not really enough to identify the particle unless I know its charge (from its motion maybe?). Is that the correct conclusion?

Comment: You're talking about Cerenkov radiation and using a Newtonian expression for momentum? Are you sure that is right?

Comment: That said, your approach has the flavor of white-board theory, but this is an intrinsically experimental question. The Cerenkov device would usually be part of system, and as such you would have some other pieces of information, so this device would be expect to provide PID over a limited set of particles consistent with that other data.  So, ask yourself instead *"How good would my measurement need to be for me to provide some kind of discrimination between particles if I already know a few things about them?"*

Comment: @dmckee Mm where did I write a Newtonian expression? If you mean my first sentence in the "attempt at an answer", I meant $p_X = \gamma_X m_X v_X = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} m_X c \implies \frac{p_X}{m_X} = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} c$. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for your comment. I must admit that thinking experimentally is not my strongest skill. For example I wonder how one can determine <$dE/dx$> without knowing the momentum of the particle?

Comment: I see. We're making different assumptions. The Cerenkov device doesn't give you $\beta \gamma$ it gives you $\beta$ and while those are equivalent in theory they are not equivalent in practice because of the finite resolution of instruments.

Comment: *"I wonder how one can determine <dE/dx> without knowing the momentum of the particle?"* Experimentors *measure* it. You can even do that *in* a Cerenkov device  under ideal circumstances (you collect both the cone and the $4\pi$ light from a ionizable Cerenkov medium), though I can't recall a case of someone using that techniques right now (I know of at least one attempt that didn't work out).

Comment: @dmckee (about $\beta$ and $\gamma$) That's interesting, would you mind explaining me the difference? Does that mean that you would usually measure $\gamma$ from the momentum if you'd know the mass of the particle?

Comment: $\frac{dE}{dx}$ is not going to be good for measuring $\beta$, even if all other factors are known. The probability of energy loss is described by the Landau distribution, which doesn't even have a mean, nor a variance. See http://meroli.web.cern.ch/meroli/Lecture_landau_ionizing_particle.html .

Comment: Have a look at this summary of particle identification methods.  https://inspirehep.net/record/884672/plots . Doing bubble chamber physics for years, the momentum was known from the curvature in the field   and the particle if of low enough  momentum  was   identified by the ionization curves , seen in the link.